# PHP can't output graphs when executing Octave program

Tags: php, image, graph, permissions, octave

I am making a php script that executes an Octave program. The Octave program produces graphical output, splits it into 4 different images with `getframe()` and saves them with `imwrite()`. Here is the output :
[output.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGu0h.jpg).
And the program :

```
function map(M,longueurMorceau=12,nbSegments=30,fps=25) 
  pkg load image;
  M = load("mat.txt");
  #rendu graphique
  colormap("jet");#changement de la colormap
  m = pcolor(M);#affichage de la map
  c = colorbar;#affichage de la barre de couleur
  axis("ij");#inversion des axes
  shading interp;#active l'interpolation
  refresh;#force le rendu graphique
  set(c,"units","pixels");
  
  #mise \ufffd l'\ufffdchelle des axes
  xlabel("t(s)"); ylabel("d(mm)");#\ufffdtiquettes
  xtick = get(gca,"XTick");#\ufffdchelle de l'axe x
  ytick = get(gca,"YTick");#\ufffdchelle de l'axe y
  set(gca,"YTick",ytick,"YTickLabel",round((ytick*longueurMorceau)/nbSegments));#mm
  set(gca,"XTick",xtick,"XTickLabel",round(xtick/fps));#s
  
  #sauvegarde des \ufffdl\ufffdments sous diff\ufffdrents fichiers
  colorbar_position = get(c,"position"); marge = 40;
  #capture du rendu
  refresh;
  f = getframe(gcf,[colorbar_position(1),colorbar_position(2)-marge,colorbar_position(3)+marge,colorbar_position(4)+marge]);
  display(f);
  #sauvegarde du fichier colorbar.png
  imwrite(f.cdata,"colorbar.jpg");

  f = getframe(gca); 
  map = imresize(f.cdata,[colorbar_position(4) 390]);#image redimensionn\ufffde 
  imwrite(map,"map.jpg");#map
  
  set(gca,"Units","pixels");
  map_position = get(gca,"position");
  f = getframe(gcf,[map_position(1)-marge,map_position(2)-marge,marge-5,map_position(4)+marge]);
  y_axis = imresize(f.cdata,[colorbar_position(4)+marge marge]);
  imwrite(y_axis,"y.jpg");#axe Y
  
  f = getframe(gcf,[map_position(1),map_position(2)-marge,map_position(3)+marge,marge-2]);
  x_axis = imresize(f.cdata,[marge 390+marge]);
  imwrite(x_axis,"x.jpg");#axe X
    
endfunction
```

When executing the program from command line, it works, and the 4 different images are stored in the current folder. But with php, things get complicated...

Here is the line of code in php that executes the Octave program :

```
 $command="sudo octave map.m";
        echo $command; 
        $out=shell_exec($command);
```

And here is the result on the browser :

[browser_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgksf.png)

Now I recognise the numbers, they are from the graph's axes, which means the program does plot something, but instead of showing it, php just prints it as raw text. As a result, `getFrame` contains no graph data, and thus, the images are not saved, because Octave needs to open a graph window in order to create the different pictures.

Could it be a permissions problem ? Like php doesn't have the right to open a graphical window ?
I really don't know how to solve this. Any help would be greatly apreciated :)

Comment: With the PHP you're only displaying whatever was output from the command line program - the same as if you were watching it in a terminal window. It's not displaying any files which might have been created. And PHP, when executed by a webserver, has no graphical shell access (it's not a permissions issue, it simply doesn't run in a GUI context), so if this program requires a graphical user context in order to work, then you've got a fundamental problem which you can't really solve - you're not going to be able to run the program successfully from the web (using PHP or any other language).

Comment: It might be worth investigating if the program itself has options though to make it not rely on the GUI. e.g. from a very quick search for "octave command line" I found https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Command-Line-Options.html#Command-Line-Options which mentions a "no-gui" option you can give to the command. I've never come across this application before today so I've no idea if that will help you or not, but it's probably worth trying. There may be other things too, I guess, have a read of the documentation. Test it from a terminal session yourself before trying it through PHP, obviously

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. When you say php doesnt run in a GUI context, what do you mean ? We can't change that ?

Comment: No you can't change that. It runs under the web server's user context, which operates as as a non-graphical user (since it's basically an automated service, it normally has no need for graphics when interacting with the O/S, it simply issues commands).

Comment: Do you understand that operating systems (especially linux and macOS) have multiple ways to log a user in? - e.g. in linux you can log in with or without the X server. If you log in with X server you get a full desktop, normal end-user experience. But if you log in without (e.g. as a terminal session, or if you log in remote via SSH) then you just get the command line interface, nothing else. Similarly in Windows, although an end-user can't usually log in with command line only, other programs which run as background services can, and do, run in a non-interactive and non-graphical session.

Comment: @ADyson Okay I understand better. I tried using the ```--no-gui``` option via the cmd and my program executes well (all the images are generated and saved). Hower, in the php, when I type ```shell_exec("sudo octave --no-gui map.m")```, it does not work. I don't understand :/

Comment: I think it's probably because `sudo` is an interactive command which requires you to enter a password. Obviously as you're executing in a non-interactive session you never get a prompt, so probably it fails, and will not execute the octave command. Does an end-user application like that really require sudo/root privileges? I wouldn't expect so normally.